# Adding days avoiding weekends

Tags: vb.net, date, addition, datetimepicker, date-arithmetic

I have 3 `DateTimePicker`, one for setting date, the second adds 3 days and the 3rd one adds 5 weekdays.  But my code don't calculate correctly.
I calculate "manually" the future days adding more or less days deppending current day.

```
  Private Sub Calculatedelivery()
    Dim normaldlvy As Integer
    Dim latedlvy As Integer
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Monday Then
        normaldlvy = 3
        latedlvy = 7
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Tuesday Then
        normaldlvy = 3
        latedlvy = 6
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Wednesday Then
        normaldlvy = 5
        latedlvy = 7
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Thursday Then
        normaldlvy = 5
        latedlvy = 7
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Friday Then
        normaldlvy = 5
        latedlvy  = 7
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Saturday Then
        normaldlvy = 4
        latedlvy = 6
    End If
    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek = Day.Sunday Then
        normaldlvy = 3
        latedlvy = 5
    End If
    DateTimePicker2.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(normaldlvy )
    DateTimePicker3.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(latedlvy)
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no simple way to add a number of weekdays to a `Date`. I would suggest a `Do` loop. Start with a number of days to add and, in the loop, add 1 day. If the result is a weekday then subtract 1 from the number.  Keep going until the number reaches zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extension method that you can call much as you already call `AddDays`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module DateTimeExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function AddWeekDays(source As Date, value As Integer) As Date
        Dim result = source

        Do
            result = result.AddDays(1)

            If result.IsWeekDay() Then
                value -= 1
            End If
        Loop Until value = 0

        Return result
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function IsWeekDay(source As Date) As Boolean
        Return source.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso
               source.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday
    End Function

End Module
```

You can then call that something like this:

```
DateTimePicker3.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddWeekDays(latedlvy)
```

Note that, unlike `Date.AddDays`, that method takes an `Integer` rather than a `Double`. Also, it will only work for positive values as it is.  It could be improved to work in pretty much exactly the way `AddDays` does but you probably don't need that in this case.

If you're not sure how extension methods work, I suggest that you do some reading on that subject.

**EDIT**: I've done some work on this method and improved it significantly.  It now handles negative and fractional values, just like `Date.AddDays` does.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

''' <summary>
''' Contains methods that extend the <see cref="DateTime"/> structure.
''' </summary>
Public Module DateTimeExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a value indicating whether a <see cref="DateTime"/> value represents a week day.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="source">
    ''' The input <see cref="DateTime"/>, which acts as the <b>this</b> instance for the extension method.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <b>true</b> if the represents a week day; otherwise <b>false</b>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' All days other than Saturday and Sunday are considered week days.
    ''' </remarks>
    <Extension>
    Public Function IsWeekDay(source As Date) As Boolean
        Return source.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday AndAlso
               source.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a new <see cref="DateTime"/> that adds the specified number of week days to a specified value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="source">
    ''' The input <see cref="DateTime"/>, which acts as the <b>this</b> instance for the extension method.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="value">
    ''' A number of whole and fractional days. The <i>value</i> parameter can be negative or positive.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' An object whose value is the sum of the date and time represented by this instance and the number of week days represented by <i>value</i>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' All days other than Saturday and Sunday are considered week days.
    ''' </remarks>
    <Extension>
    Public Function AddWeekDays(source As Date, value As Double) As Date
        'A unit will be +/- 1 day.
        Dim unit = Math.Sign(value) * 1.0

        'Start increasing the date by units from the initial date.
        Dim result = source

        'When testing for zero, allow a margin for precision error.
        Do Until Math.Abs(value) < 0.00001
            If Math.Abs(value) < 1.0 Then
                'There is less than one full day to add so we need to see whether adding it will take us past midnight.
                Dim temp = result.AddDays(value)

                If temp.Date = result.Date OrElse temp.IsWeekDay() Then
                    'Adding the partial day did not take us into a weekend day so we're done.
                    result = temp
                    value = 0.0
                Else
                    'Adding the partial day took us into a weekend day so we need to add another day.
                    result = result.AddDays(unit)
                End If
            Else
                'Add a single day.
                result = result.AddDays(unit)

                If result.IsWeekDay() Then
                    'Adding a day did not take us into a weekend day so we can reduce the remaining value to add.
                    value -= unit
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I've added a new implementation of the extension provided earlier that improves on that original.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this. One that I think it fairly straight forward - especially if you're only doing the calculation a few times.

```
Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date

Dim dates = _
        Enumerable _
            .Range(1, 100000) _
            .Select(Function (x) someDate.AddDays(x)) _
            .Where(Function (x) x.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday) _
            .Where(Function (x) x.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday)

Dim nextDate = dates.Take(5).First()
```

The big advantage with this approach is that you can also add further `.Where` calls to remove public holidays.

Simple.